# Reactjs, CSS - why my grid doesn't display element correctly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm working currently with Reactjs, GridCss in Gatsby framework. I'm trying to build a subgrid in a subcomponent of the Gatsby layout.js file. 
But when I have finished setting my grid, the subcomponent fails to display the component in their good place. When I'm trying to display the grid on the Firefox browser with the special's Firefox plugin, the grid fails to appear.

The footer component is imported from a file called footer.js. Normally the footer contains two columns, one for social media items, and the another for the subscription to newsletter form. 
Everything is well displayed but not the footer, this is the footer grid which fails to display well.

Here my layout.js :

```
<div >
    <div className={style.header}>
      <div className= {style.headbar}> 
        <div className={style.headerLeft}>
          <Logo className={style.logo} /> 

        </div>
        <div className={style.headerRight}>
          <Menu className={style.menu}/> 
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    <Chat/>

   <div className={style.children}>
    {children()} 
    </div>

    <div> 
    <Footer  className={style.footer} /> // everything is well display but not the footer, this is the footer grid which fails to display well

    </div>
  </div>
```

my layout.css :

```
.layout{ 
    width: 100%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
    display : grid; 
    grid-template-areas:  
                "header   header"
                "children children"
                "footer   footer" ;             
}

{...}

.footer{ 
    height: 20em;
    width: 100vw; 
    grid-area: footer; 
    background-color: white; 
}
```

my footer.js ° imported from footer.js ° :

```
export default () => {
  return (
    <div className={style.footer_grid}>
            <div className={style.social_media}>
             social media
            </div>
            <div className={style.newsletter_subscription}>
            subscriptionewsletter
            </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

my footer.css :

```
.footer_grid{       
width: 100vw; 
display:grid;
grid-template-areas: 
    "footer_social_media  footer_newsletter_subscription";
grid-template-columns:  2.5fr 1fr; 
} 

.social_media{ 
grid-area: footer_social_media;
display : flex; 
justify-content: center; 
align-items: center
}

.newsletter_subscription{ 
grid-area: footer_newsletter_subscription; 
display : flex; 
justify-content: end; 
align-items: start;
}
```

Despite I have been careful to follow all the grid rules, my grid fails to be displayed properly.

If someone has any hint, would be great,
Thanks

Comment: answer : in gatsby, you got to name your css module file name.module.css

Comment: Please post this as an answer so that others may benefit in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer : in gatsby, you got to name your css module file name.module.css